# Firebase Crashlytics xCode React Native issue in RNFirebaseCrashlytics

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have a problem during the configuration about the crashlytics integration.

I configured correctly the sdk into the app.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image2]

I insert firebase.crashlytics().crash(); for simulate the crash, but I receive this issue (below the image) and I don't see the crash in the firebase dashboard.

[image]

How can I solve the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your xcode from your simulator / device before crashing the app. In this case the xcode debugger intercepts the crash and the report is not sent over to crashlytics

Comment: I disconnected the debug, I'm building in release mode on a  real device, but I don't receive the crash in firebase console.